# How to redirect all requests not going to a subdirectory into that subdirectory?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mediawiki

I have moved an application (a mediawiki installation) from the root directory into a subdirectory.

`/Article_Name` is now `/wiki/Article_Name`

I need an htaccess that redirects all 404 requests that are not inside `/wiki/`, into `/wiki/`, retaining the remainder of the request, like with my example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code redirects (301=Moved Permanently) all non-existing files to the wiki-directory, keeping the article name etc. Using the 301 will also indicate that these files are moved and the search engines will start using the new name (can take a while).

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wiki/$1 [R=301,L]
```